# Error on android and ios platforms, in the HttpClient.GetAsync (Uri RequestUri) function for redirect url

Tags: c#, redirect, xamarin

I'm developing a Xamarin Forms application that basically uses the GetAsync (Uri requestUri) function through the HttpClient:

```
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(new NativeMessageHandler());
    var uri = new Uri(http://www.appwebservice.meusite.com.br);
    httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
```

This url automatically redirects to another url with ip (something like that http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81/AppWebServiceBase/AppService.svc/json/WebServiceUrl), 
but this redirection isn't done by the app but by the hosting service itself, 
let's say if i put the link http://www.appwebservice.meusite.com.br in the browser it will be automatically redirected to the url http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81/AppWebServiceBase/AppService.svc/json/WebServiceUrl.

On the UWP platform this works properly, however on Android and iOS platforms it gives error.

Android Error

```
   --- End of managed Java.Net.MalformedURLException stack trace ---
   java.net.MalformedURLException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "81\AppWebServiceBase\AppService.svc\json\WebServiceUrl"
   at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:192)
   at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:139)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.followUpRequest(HttpEngine.java:1009)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponse(Call.java:285)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$ApplicationInterceptorChain.proceed(Call.java:228)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(Call.java:199)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call.access$100(Call.java:34)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.Call$AsyncCall.execute(Call.java:162)
   at com.squareup.okhttp.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:33)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

iOS error:

```
   Invalid URI: Invalid port specified.
   at System.Uri.CreateThis (System.String uri, System.Boolean dontEscape, System.UriKind uriKind) [0x0007b] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/UriExt.cs:55 
   at System.Uri..ctor (System.String uriString) [0x00014] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/System/net/System/URI.cs:408 
   at ModernHttpClient.NativeMessageHandler+DataTaskDelegate.DidReceiveResponse (Foundation.NSUrlSession session, Foundation.NSUrlSessionDataTask dataTask, Foundation.NSUrlResponse response, System.Action`1[T] completionHandler) [0x00106] in /Users/paul/code/paulcbetts/modernhttpclient/src/ModernHttpClient/iOS/NSUrlSessionHandler.cs:184 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:152 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00037] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00028] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00008] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/11.6.1.4/src/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
   at OuvidoriaApp.Services.SaudeWebService+<ServiceCall>d__0.MoveNext () [0x000f1] in C:\Workspace\OuvidoriaApp\OuvidoriaApp\OuvidoriaApp\Services\OuvidoriaWebService.cs:44
```

If I put the url already redirected, ie put the address with IP the application works normally, the problem seems to be at www address ...

When I disable Auto Redirect the httpResponseMessage receives the following values:

```
    ReasonPhrase: Moved Temporarily
    StatusCode: 302 (System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Found)
    IsSuccessStatusCode: false
    Content: 
    <html>
        <head><title>Object moved</title></head>
        <body>
            <h2>Object moved to <a href="http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81\AppWebServiceBase\AppService.svc\json\WebServiceUrl">here</a>.</h2>
        </body> 
        and here messages to the user saying that an error has occurred
    </html>
```

This href on content (http://xxx.xx.xxx.xx:81\AppWebServiceBase\AppService.svc\json\WebServiceUrl) is the correct redirection I need.

Note: I changed the urls and made the error handling, I put in a summarized way where the error is located, I hope it was clear in the doubt.

Comment: You can disable the automatic redirect to check if the server is returning something strange in the URL, if everything seems ok you can always use that response and manually connect to the redirect URL.

Comment: @Gusman I did what you recommended and I updated the question with this new information, thanks.

Comment: The slashes in the redirect URL are the wrong way.

Comment: IF that's all the response you receive it's missing the "Location" header, that's why it does not work.

Comment: @Gusman I don't know where and how I specify the location in the header, because this error only appears when I disable the auto redirect, if I activate the auto redirect the breakpoint doesn't reach this point, it gives error before, at the time of GetAsync

Comment: The header must not be added by you, is the server the one who must add it to the response. Check on the response (without the redirect) if the headers contains a "Location" one, if it does not contain it then the server is not working correctly, if it contains that header then check if the URL is wellformed. Also, CodeCaster is right, the slashes are wrong. In any way, the problem is in the server, but you can "patch" it manually, continue with the redirect disabled, take the URL from the Location header or from the body, replace the slashes and redo the request to the parsed location

Comment: @Gusman It's strange but I checked the slashes and it's correct. Can I draw any conclusion from the fact that it only works for UWP and not for Android and iOS?

Comment: Try the solution I gave before, call the service without redirect, extract the Location header and redo the request to the received location. If it works then there may be a bug in the Mono framework.